# installation of fftw on ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, install-from-source

i am installing fftw but it gives error  and terminal shows this

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/suraj/Desktop/fftw/api'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/suraj/Desktop/fftw/api'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 fftw3.h fftw3.f fftw3l.f03 fftw3q.f03 '/usr/local/include'
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/include/fftw3.h’: Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/include/fftw3.f’: Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/include/fftw3l.f03’: Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/local/include/fftw3q.f03’: Permission denied
make[3]: *** [install-includeHEADERS] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/suraj/Desktop/fftw/api'
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/suraj/Desktop/fftw/api'
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/suraj/Desktop/fftw/api'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple thing. You try to MAKE INSTALL as a normal user, and a normal user can't put the files into those directories, because the user is not allowed to do that.

Try the following

```
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: It is not necessary to use `sudo` for `make`.

Comment: I stand corrected, it's only necessary for make install, I will change my answer